# Issue passing date type with f:param

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I'm trying to filter a listPage by date and userid. From a datatable the selected userid and date value is passed to the listPage with the f:param tag. The list page shows an error that says "value must be a date"  and the filter doesnt work. It works if its just filtered by userid without the date. What could I be doing wrong? or How can I get this to work? I've also tried using the JBoss seam date converter that doesnt work too.

Heres my code:

**firstPage.xhtml**

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{_auditEventFact[3]}">
            </h:outputText>
</h:column>



    <rich:column styleClass="action">
        <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>  
    <s:link value="View" view="/AuditEventFactList.xhtml" action="# auditEventFactList.lookUpUserAuditRecords()}">
    <f:param name="userid" value="#{_auditEventFact[1]}"/>
    <f:param name="ntimestamp" value="#{_auditEventFact[3]}"/>
  </s:link>                                             
    </rich:column>
```

**pages.xml**

```
<param name="from"/>
   <param name="userid" value="#{auditEventFactList.auditEventFact.userid}"/>
   <param name="ntimestamp" value="#{auditEventFactList.auditEventFact.ntimestamp}" converterId="javax.faces.DateTime"/>
```

**ListAction.java**

```
private static final String EJBQL = "select auditEventFact from AuditEventFact auditEventFact";
private static final String[] RESTRICTIONS = {
        "lower(auditEventFact.userid) like concat(lower(#{auditEventFactList.auditEventFact.userid}),'%')",
        "auditEventFact.ntimestamp = #{auditEventFactList.auditEventFact.ntimestamp}",
        "lower(auditEventFact.auditid) like concat(lower(#{auditEventFactList.auditEventFact.auditid}),'%')", };

private AuditEventFact auditEventFact = new AuditEventFact();   
public AuditEventFactList() {
    setEjbql(EJBQL);
    setRestrictionExpressionStrings(Arrays.asList(RESTRICTIONS));
    setMaxResults(25);
}
```

**EntityBean.java**

```
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="NTIMESTAMP#", length=11)
    public Date getNtimestamp() {
        return this.ntimestamp1;
    }

    public void setNtimestamp(Date ntimestamp1) {
        this.ntimestamp1 = ntimestamp1;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't do Seam, so I can't give a Seam-targeted answer. But basically, the `f:param` sets a HTTP request parameter which can contain only strings since they are transferred in ASCII flavor as per the HTTP specification. It isn't been passed as a fullworthy `java.util.Date` object as you seem to expect. Instead, the outcome of `String.valueOf(date)` is been passed. Its format is specified in [`Date#toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29).

In plain JSF terms, there are two solutions:

1. Use `<h:commandLink>` instead in combination with `f:setPropertyActionListener` it is capable of "passing" fullworthy non-standard Java objects as "parameters".

   ```
   <h:commandLink value="View" action="#{auditEventFactList.lookUpUserAuditRecords}">
       <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{entityBean.ntimestamp}" value="#{_auditEventFact[3]}"/>
   </h:commandLink>
   ```
2. Use `String` instead of `Date` in `ntimestamp` or wrap another `String` setter around it which converts the `String` to `Date` and delegates to the original `Date` setter. The [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) may be helpful in this.

See if this is doable in combination with Seam.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the `<s:convertDateTime />` tag on a parameter?  I've never tried it myself, but it's worth looking in to.